# Ошибка WinLogon 4005 Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7

Подскажите как бороться с этой ошибкой. Постоянно появляется в журнале за 24 часа по 5 штук минимум.

> ```
> Winlogonкод ошибки 4005"Вход был неожиданно завершен"
> ```

Windows 7 x64 выступает в качестве терминального сервера (пропатчен). 1С. MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Когда начали появляться такие ошибки? Установлен ли SP1 на Windows 7?Вот [ссылка](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348728(WS.10).aspx) на описание вашей ошибки. Если не сильны в английском, то вот ссылка с автопереводом.

Comment: Когда не знаю, СП1 стоит... по ссылка прошел, все нормально вроде с этим.